# Retornar o segundo maior elemento de uma árvore binária

Tags: java

estou com dificuldades em criar uma método que retorna o segundo maior elemento de uma árvore. Meu código de retornar o maior elemento ficou assim:

```java
    public int maiorElemento () {
        return maiorElemento(raiz);
    }

    private int maiorElemento(No i) {
        int maior=i.elemento;

        if(i.dir!=null) { 
            maior=maiorElemento(i.dir);
        }

        return maior;
    }
```

Acho que minha dificuldade em criar é: em caso de o maior ser o i.dir e houver por exemplo, o elemento i.esq.dir (que seria o segundo maior).

Comment: Seja bem vindo Stenio, para que possamos rodar e trazer uma resposta melhor é interessante que você coloque mais detalhes do seu código.

Comment: Onde se encontra o `i.esq.dir` em seu código?

Comment: Poste o codigo completo, deste jeito não tem como ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz de uma forma e testei algumas vezes e consegui. Porém ainda sinto que falta alguma coisa hahah. Segue código:

```java
    public int segundoMaior () {
        return segundoMaior(raiz);
    }

    private int segundoMaior(No i) {

        int segMaior=i.elemento;

        if (i.dir!=null ) {
            if(i.dir.dir!=null) {   
                 segMaior=segundoMaior(i.dir);

            } else if (i.dir.esq!=null) {
                segMaior=segundoMaior(i.dir.esq);
            }
        }


        return segMaior;      
    }
```

Comment: Se puder postar o código completo  !